# How to force pip to install latest requirement.txt versions without use cache?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have this requirements.txt

```
esphome
tornado
esptool
pyparsing >=3.0
```

When I call it with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: esphome in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (2023.6.4)

But if I see on searching on https://pypi.org/search/?q=esphome I see:
[image: newer esphome version]

How can I let `pip` known that a new version exists? As workaround I am changing the dependency manually but I always want to use the latest versions of `esphome`.

I already tried the `--no-cache-dir` flag but it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can specify the option `--upgrade` to `pip install`, and additionally perhaps specify that your upgrade strategy should be `eager`

From `pip install --help`:

> `-U, --upgrade`               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of
> dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.
>
> `--upgrade-strategy <upgrade_strategy>`
> Determines how dependency upgrading should be handled [default: only-if-needed].
> "eager" - dependencies are upgraded regardless of whether the currently installed
> version satisfies the requirements of the upgraded package(s). "only-if-needed" -  are
> upgraded only when they do not satisfy the requirements of the upgraded package(s)

Looks like you'll only need `--upgrade-strategy eager` if you want your implicit dependencies (the stuff that esphome, esptool, tornado, and pyparsing depend on) to also be upgraded to latest rather than only upgrading if the current version is insufficient.

Comment: It did not work, calling ` pip install --upgrade-strategy eager -r requirements.txt` still skips versions :/

Comment: @distante `--upgrade` is a required option: `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`, `pip install -U --upgrade-strategy eager -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @distante as phd rightly points out in the previous comment, you must have misread my answer which indicates that `--upgrade` (or its short form `-U`) is required. My answer additionally explains how `--upgrade-strategy` can be used to upgrade the implicit dependencies, but `--upgrade` is what you're looking for for your explicit dependencies.

Comment: Sorry! I now understand.